# How can I convert an annular sector to a rectangular region?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, geometry

I have an annular region $v=\{(r,\theta): r_1<r<r_2, a<\theta<b\} $. How can I transform this region to  a rectangular region $u=\{(x,y): -1<x<1, m<y<n\} $? Thanks..

Comment: what kind of transformation are you looking for? what is the context in which you encountered this question?

Comment: i am working on fluid flow problem in the annular region. But i have some problems about fluid structures. So 
i want to compare rectangles with annular.  Actually, may be i need a conformal mapping between these regions.

Answer (score 0):

Call

$$
x = 2\frac{r - r_1}{r_2 - r_1} - 1 ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ y = \theta
$$